# Adding views to a LinearLayout in a ViewFlipper

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, viewflipper

I am attempting to add a number of LinearLayouts (which are used as pages, cast as ViewGroups to allow me to child views) to a ViewFlipper (to allow me to flip through the pages). I then need to add content to the pages.

So far, all necessary pages are created, however they are empty.
There are two ways I have tried to achieve this -

```
int currentNote = 0;
int currentPage = -1;
int pagesRequired = _numberOfPagesRequired;

// I am using ViewGroups as this is the only way I can find to add child LinearLayouts (stored in their own Views) to the page
ViewGroup[] notesPageInflatedLayout = new ViewGroup[pagesRequired];

foreach (CaseNote caseNote in foundCase.Notes)
{
    // If currentNote is 0 or a multiple of 10
    if (currentNote % 10 == 0)
    {
        // Increment the currentPage
        currentPage++;

        // Create a new page
        LayoutInflater notesPageLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        notesPageInflatedLayout[currentPage] = notesPageLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_notes_page, null) as ViewGroup;

        // Set the TextView at the top of the page to the page number
        TextView temp = notesPageInflatedLayout[currentPage].FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.temp);
        temp.Text = currentPage.ToString();

        // Add the page to the ViewFlipper
        NotesViewFlipper.AddView(notesPageInflatedLayout[currentPage]);
    }

    // Create content item (note)
    LayoutInflater notesLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
    View notesInflatedLayout = notesLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_note, null);

    TextView nameEntryTypeTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameEntryTypeTextView);
    nameEntryTypeTextView.Text = "TBI - " + caseNote.EntryType;

    TextView detailsTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailsTextView);
    detailsTextView.Text = caseNote.Details;

    TextView dateTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dateTextView);
    dateTextView.Text = caseNote.Date.ToShortDateString();

    // Add content item to current page and increment note number
    notesPageInflatedLayout[currentPage].AddView(notesInflatedLayout);
    currentNote++;
}
```

...and...

```
int currentPage = 0;

while (foundCase.Notes.Count > 0)
{
    List<CaseNote> chunk = foundCase.Notes.Take(10).ToList();
    foundCase.Notes.RemoveRange(0, chunk.Count);

    LayoutInflater notesPageLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
    ViewGroup notesPageInflatedLayout = notesPageLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_notes_page, null) as ViewGroup;

    TextView temp = notesPageInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.temp);
    temp.Text = currentPage.ToString();

    NotesViewFlipper.AddView(notesPageInflatedLayout);

    foreach (CaseNote caseNote in chunk)
    {
        LayoutInflater notesLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        View notesInflatedLayout = notesLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view_note, null);

        TextView nameEntryTypeTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameEntryTypeTextView);
        nameEntryTypeTextView.Text = "TBI - " + caseNote.EntryType;

        TextView detailsTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailsTextView);
        detailsTextView.Text = caseNote.Details;

        TextView dateTextView = notesInflatedLayout.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.dateTextView);
        dateTextView.Text = caseNote.Date.ToShortDateString();

        notesPageInflatedLayout.AddView(notesInflatedLayout);
    }

    currentPage++;
}
```

Both of these methods work correctly when there are 10 or less items (so only one page is being added). See below screenshots.

Expected output (which is visible when only one page is created) -

[image: Output]

Output when more than one page is created (all pages are blank) -

[image: Output]

Out of curiosity, I tried changing the ViewFlipper to a LinearLayout. All pages, as expected, displayed one after the other. This leads me to believe that this may be down to the way I have built my layout. You can find my AXML -

view_notes.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/notesViewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- <include layout="@layout/view_notes_page"/> -->
        </ViewFlipper>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigationRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <Button
                android:text="Previous"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="Add Note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addNoteButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

view_notes_page.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/notesLinearLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Notes"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <!-- <include layout="@layout/view_note"/> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

view_note.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/case_type_background_top"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/nameEntryTypeTextView"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/case_type_background_bottom">
        <ImageButton
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_fullscreen_24"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/viewImageButton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_edit_24"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/editImageButton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_remove_circle_24"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/removeImageButton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have many data, why not to used the `RecyclerView` to achieve that?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/, if you still want to used `ViewFlipper`, if you can get error or warring in your logcat?

Comment: I have had a look at `RecyclerView` and it doesn't seem suitable for what I'm trying to achieve. As for the logcat, I can't see anything that seems to pertain to what's happening, I've uploaded it to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jS5vNkkP) if you'd like to take a look.